# connect from android simulator to application on pc

Tags: android, networking

I am running a android application on a simulator.
This android application tries to connect to a application running on the same PC.
How can i achieve this, since the simulator does not recognise 127.0.0.01

The application on my PC is listening on port 8000. The client application is a android application trying to connect to this port 8000.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely you are using the android *emulator* (the android *simulator* is an obscure and deprecated beast).  The android emulator documentation specifies an alias address in the 10.x.x.x network where the hosting machine's loopback interface may be accessed.  Please note this works *only* on the emulator, and not on ADB connected physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access `10.0.2.2:8000`.

`10.0.2.2` is "*Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)*".

**Network Address Space**
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

If an app is executed in the emulator 127.0.0.1 refers to the localhost interface of the emulator, not to the OS executing the emulatior.

For accessing the localhost interface of your PC there are special IP addresses available in the emulator.

Use **10.0.2.2:8000** for accessing the service from within the emulator.

The complete list of pre-defined IP addresses inside the emulator is documented here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses